# Array data not saving when pushed into vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am creating a custom resource file, however when I set up dummy data and push it onto the containers stack, the values in the array become null. I have an idea as to why it happens(the array data is destroyed when the containing block finishes), but I have no idea on how to prevent it from being destroyed.

```
#pragma once


#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef __RFNAME
#define __RFNAME "resource.dat"
#endif


using namespace std;

namespace rf {


    struct rfHEADER {
        uint32_t _versionNumber;
    };

    struct rfIMAGE {
        uint32_t _sizeOfData;
        uint32_t *_data;
    };

    struct rfSOUND {

    };

    class rfFILE {

    public:
        //Constructors
        rfFILE() 
        { 
            //Create a dummy header
            HEADER._versionNumber = 16;

            //Create a dummy image
            uint32_t imageArrData[] = {10, 52, 18, 1, 19, 20, 20, 10, 4, 10};
            rfIMAGE i;
            i._sizeOfData = 10;
            i._data = imageArrData;
            IMAGEDATA.push_back(i);

            //Does the data stay when the rfIMAGE data is pushed onto the vector?
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                printf("Test image data is: %d\n", IMAGEDATA.front()._data[j]);
            }

        }
        ~rfFILE() { }

        void test()
        {
            //Modify dummy data
            HEADER._versionNumber = 9;

            rfIMAGE i = IMAGEDATA.front();

            uint32_t imageArrData[] = {0};
            i._data = imageArrData;
            i._sizeOfData = 1;

            IMAGEDATA.front() = i;

        }

        void printVersionNumber() {
            printf("The current version number is... %d\n", HEADER._versionNumber);


            printf("The image data size is... %d\n", IMAGEDATA.front()._sizeOfData);
            printf("The image data is...\n");
            for(uint32_t i = 0; i < IMAGEDATA.front()._sizeOfData; i++)
            {
                printf("%d\t", IMAGEDATA.front()._data[i]);
            }

        }

        //Reads from a resource file
        void readFromFile()
        {
            //set the resource file name
            const char* filename = __RFNAME;

            //Set up the instream
            ifstream iStream;
            iStream.open(filename, ios_base::binary);

            //If the instream is open
            if(iStream.is_open()) {
                //Read the first 4 bytes into the header
                iStream.read((char*)&HEADER, sizeof(HEADER));




                //close the instream
                iStream.close();
            }

        }

        //Write to a resource file
        void writeToFile()
        {
            //set the resource file name that we will be writing to
            const char* fileName = __RFNAME;
            //Set up the outstream
            ofstream oStream;
            oStream.open(fileName, ios_base::binary);

            //if the stream is open
            if(oStream.is_open()) {

                //write the header
                oStream.write((char*)&HEADER, sizeof(HEADER));

                //Write how many elements are in the IMAGEDATA stack (4 bytes)
                oStream.write((char*)IMAGEDATA.size(), sizeof(IMAGEDATA.size()));
                //Loop through n times and write the image data, where n is the number of elements in IMAGEDATA
                for(int i = 0; i < IMAGEDATA.size(); i++) {
                    uint32_t datasize = IMAGEDATA[i]._sizeOfData;
                    oStream.write((char*)IMAGEDATA[i]._sizeOfData, sizeof(IMAGEDATA[i]._sizeOfData));
                    oStream.write((char*)IMAGEDATA[i]._data, datasize);
                }

                //Close the stream
                oStream.close();
            }



        }



    private:
        rfHEADER HEADER;
        vector<rfIMAGE> IMAGEDATA;
        vector<rfSOUND> SOUNDDATA;

    protected:
        rfFILE(const rfFILE& copy) { }
    };
}
```

Any ideas on how to keep the values put into the dummy rfIMAGE and pushed onto the vector after the block the dummy data is declared in leaves scope?

Comment: A few coding hints: using namespace std in a header is an absolute no-go, even one of the worst! You are forcing everyone using your header to include each and every bit of STL that has been included in your header or any preceding include of an STL header. In general: Just forget that using namespace can even be used inside the global scope. Next: Use an std::vector for the data in the rfImage instead of a pointer, you can then drop the sizeOfData.

Comment: @Muepe I've tried to point out your mentions in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide your `imageArrData` dummy as `static` function local variable in your constructor, otherwise the data goes out of scope as soon the constructor function is left:

```
//Constructors
rfFILE() { 
   //Create a dummy header
   HEADER._versionNumber = 16;

   //Create a dummy image
   static uint32_t imageArrData[] = {10, 52, 18, 1, 19, 20, 20, 10, 4, 10};
// ^^^^^^
```

**UPDATE**
Another (better) option is to hold your whole image data in a `std::vector<uint32_t>` instead of using a plain pointer and size, e.g.:

```
typedef std::vector<uint32_t> rfIMAGE;
```

To interact with raw `uint32_t* data` pointers given along with a `size_t size` parameter, you can use the [`std::vector<>::assign()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) method:

```
rfIMAGE image;

void setImage(uint32_t* imgData, size_t imgSize) {
    assert(imgData);
    image.assign(imgData,imgData + imgSize);
}
```

Comment: I'll probably switch to using a vector to store my data, that is a good idea. There's going to be more data in the rfIMAGE than just the raw image data, though. But thank you and Muepe for the idea !

Answer (score 1):

Instead of allocating on the stack, try allocating your data on the heap instead.
Stack data is effectively gone when the code block in which it was allocated finishes.

Replace this line:

```
uint32_t imageArrData[] = {10, 52, 18, 1, 19, 20, 20, 10, 4, 10};
```

With the following, and then assign your elements.

```
uint32_t* imageArrData = new uint32_t[10];
imageArrData[0] = 10;
imageArrData[1] = 52;
...
```

Comment: Why `malloc()`, why heap allocation for _dummy_ data at all? Would just complicate everything, and call for memory leaks ...

Comment: Look at what the OP is asking for.

Comment: The data is destroyed when scope of the constructor is left, and? So  what, make it `static` and everything's fine.

Comment: While both this and assigning the variable as static both work, this works better for when I want to test having multiple rfIMAGE objects in the vector. I wish I could assign two answers, since both you and πάντα ῥεῖ reminded me of how memory works.

EDIT: And the dummy data won't exist when I finish this, I'll be removing it from the ctor, so leaked memory is not really a concern.

Comment: OP is using C++, so why rely on an old and (in my opinion) deprecated C-function? If one roots for manual memory management using `uint32_t* imageArrData = new uint32_t[10];` and once its no longer used `delete [] imageArrData;` is a much better idea.

Comment: _Stack data tends to get killed ..._ It doesn't _tend_, but definitely **will be** killed.

Comment: Not true. When the stack is popped, there is no guarantee that the memory location will be overwritten immediately. I agree that it will eventually get killed though.

Comment: @merlin2011 You can't rely, so you have to consider it to be killed. It's simply UB.

Comment: @merlin2011 Little correction: `uint32_t* imageArrData = ...` and not `uint32_t imageArrData*`. Cant edit, edits have to be at least 6 characters.